# Как сделать, чтобы не оставалось пустое место в ячейках таблицы?

Tags: html

Как сделать, чтобы не оставалось пустое место в ячейках?

Вот код

```
<td width="74%" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" ">
    <tr>
        <td width="24%" align="center"> Информация</td>
        <td width="47%" align="center">Адрес</td>
        <td width="12%">Площадь</td>
        <td width="8%">Комнат</td>
        <td width="3%">Цена</td>
        <td width="3%"><p>Добавлено</p></td>
```

Comment: уберите все `width="*%"`

Comment: А как потом давать ширину ячейкам,через пиксели?

Comment: а зачем, если Вам нужно, что бы не оставалось пустого места?

Comment: Ну мне же нужно,чтобы одна ячейка была шире другой

Comment: http://property.az/search.php?type=kvartira&cel=prodat примерно как вот тут

Comment: @aaa, а ничего, что на странице, куда ведет ваша ссылка, вообще нет ни одного элемента `<table>`? То есть, абсолютно.

Comment: Таблицы так сделаны что нужно либо задать правильные размеры ячеек, либо увеличить шрифт что бы пустое место ним было забито, либо убрать величины вовсе и тогда таблица автоматически настроит ячейки размера по контенту. Вопрос неоднозначный, чего вы именно хотите?